# How to add an SD Card to GRUB Bootloader

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 22.04, chromeos

I'm running Ubuntu Studio 22.04 dual-booted with Windows 11, and I want to add an SD card with FydeOS to my GRUB menu... The issue is I don't know how...
I've tried adding `/dev/sda` to the bootloader through grub editor, but nothing new shows.

Comment: You can add a grub entry to boot the other OS (*make the change on Ubuntu Studio 22.04 LTS if it controls your booting*) via either `chainloader`  (*if you're going to use the other OSes boot loader, or as per duplicate*)  or create an entry to boot the OS directly (*this method will differ, but I don't know FydeOS as it's not Ubuntu, nor on-topic here, thus don't know how it would appear as entries can vary for GNU/Linux, BSD, windows, MacOS etc*)

Comment: Install the OS to USB, Copy it's grub menuentry to Ubuntu Studio's grub.cfg.